# How do I display custom error page using errorhandler in my function?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I'm validating the string to contain only alphabetic characters and if not want to display custom error page on the browser. I have used Flask and Python. I'm getting proper result if the string contains only alphabetic characters and other custom error handlers are working fine. But if I give value like alphanumeric or any number it is not handling the defined error instead it's giving me 500 error. Can anyone suggest me where I'm going wrong?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('__name__')

@app.route('/user/<username>')
def str_val(username):
    for letter in username:
        if letter.isalpha() != True:
            raise TypeError('Only alphabets are allowed') 
    return 'Hello {}'.format(username)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return '<h4> Please Check the Spelling and retry the URL</h4>', 404

@app.errorhandler(TypeError)
def wrong_input(error):
    return '<h1> only alpha characters are allowed</h1>'
```

TypeError is giving me message in console but I want it to be displayed on browser.

Comment: I am getting the expected error message in the browser if I try to visit route containing alphanumeric username e.g: http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/test123. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/OXBZwTI

Comment: I'm getting the same as @arsho. Also, it is currently returning a 200 HTTP code, you should consider using a 400 instead. By the way, which URL are you testing the code with?

Comment: @arsho yes, I'm getting the result. Might be it was not refreshed. Thanks for checking